# What should be the on-topic list of questions on the FAQ page?

Tags: discussion, faq

We can edit the faq page to clarify what is **on** topic.

See https://cooking.stackexchange.com/faq (among others) for an example.

Answer below with the bulleted list of what is **on**-topic and we'll see if we can help define at a high level what is **on** topic for inclusion in the faq.

---

Update:  I made the initial changes to the [FAQ page](https://money.stackexchange.com/faq) based on the answer to this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should be the off-topic list of questions on the FAQ page?](http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/201/what-should-be-the-off-topic-list-of-questions-on-the-faq-page)

Comment: @Dheer Not a duplicate.  Contrast **on** -topic vs. **off** -topic.

Comment: Opps you got me there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Personal investing and asset allocation
- The financial aspects of homebuying
- Best practices for saving for retirement, education, and other goals
- Strategies for creating and sticking to a budget
- Strategies for earning and saving more money

I'm marking CW to make editing easier.

Comment: What about adding as the first bullet: "Questions that have answers"?